# audio file doesn't work on ios iphone neither safari nor chrome

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, iphone, html5-audio

I'm creating a chat with the ability to send voice notes.
and voice notes work perfectly on desktop and android but on ios things start to crash

once the audio files load, the chrome console on ios shows an error
`mediaError {code:4, message:Unsupported source type, MEDIA_ERR_ABORTED:1, MEDIA_ERR_NETWORK:2, MEDIA_ERR_DECODE:3}`

and if I click on the play button it gives the error `DOMException`

**This is the function that records audio**

```
const recordAudio = async (_) => {
  const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true })
  const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, {
      mimeType:'audio/mp4',
      audioBitrate: '128000',
 })
  mediaRecorder.start()
  const audioChunks = []
  mediaRecorder.addEventListener('dataavailable', (event) => {
    audioChunks.push(event.data)
  })

  mediaRecorder.addEventListener('stop', () => {
    const audioBlob = new Blob(audioChunks, { type: 'audio/mp3' })
    composeMessage('audio', audioBlob)
    setIsRecording(false)
  })

  setTimeout(() => {
    mediaRecorder.stop()
  }, 30000)
}
```

**The function that creates audio file**

```
const createAudioFile = () => {
  const audio = new Audio()
  audio.setAttribute('preload', 'metadata')
  const source = document.createElement('source')
  source.setAttribute('src', URL)
  source.setAttribute('type', 'audio/mp3')
  audio.appendChild(source)
  setAudioFile(audio)
}
```

**and this is the function that triggers the audio file**

```
const playAudioHandler = () => {
  const playPromise = audioFile.play()
  if (playPromise !== undefined) {
     playPromise
    .then((_) => {
      audioFile.play()
      setIsPlaying(true)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      pauseAudioHandler()
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: The file you are trying to play is not supported in Safari. Try using mp4.

Comment: when i tried to add mimetype in mediaRecorder `{mimeType:audio/mp4}` , it gives error `unsupported mimeType` on windows and android but not on ios devices, and audio file actually runs on ios devices, so how can I record with this mimeType on windows and android

Comment: not sure. audio/mp4 should be working. Could you post a link to your app demo.

Comment: @aleksa_95 I updated the code and added the options object to mediaRecorder API